# Can I make IE7, HTML5 Form Validation, and jQuery .submit event work together

Tags: jquery, forms, html, validation, internet-explorer-7

This is my form:

```
<div id="MyModal" class="m-modal-container">
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <form id="form_reg" class="m-form reg-form" action="www.somedomain.com/subPage">
      <div class="form-element email">
    <input type="email" class="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" title="Email is required." maxlength="90" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="button primary submit">Register</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is from my JS file to handle the submit

```
$("#MyModal #form_reg").submit(function(event){
    var initial_id = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/dir/file.cfc',
        async: false,
        data: {
            method: 'myFunction', 
            emailAddress: $("#MyModal #form_reg").find('[name="email"]').val(), 
            email_id: 0
        },
        cache: false,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .success(function(response) { initial_id = response.jsid; }) 
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { })
    .complete(function(response) { 
        if (initial_id == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#MyModal').dialog('close');
            return false;               
        }
    });
});
```

My question:

This form displays as a modal over the main page.  The user fills it out, and clicks the submit and it goes to a new page.  It uses HTML5 form validation to indicate required fields.  It uses webShims/polyfill for older browser compatibility.

That all works as it should.  My issues arises in certain circumstances, I do not want the form to submit to the "subPage" (the default action on the form).  Instead I want it to simply close the modal-form, staying on the page that displayed the modal.  (This occurs in the event that the email is already in the system - do not want to take the user to the secondary form page showing a message that the email is already in the system).

If I use $("#MyModal #form_reg").click(function(event){ blah blah blah }); - then I can control the submission vs. non-submission.  However, I then lose the HTML5 form validation feature.  If I use $("#MyModal #form_reg").submit(function(event){ blah blah blah }); the form validation works, but the page submits and the event is not being captured by the code.

All the researching I've done to date indicates that IE7 does not play well with the .submit event, however, I need the .submit event for the form validation to work.

Is there a way for these three things to work together?  IE7 is the only browser causing my issue.  the .submit/form validation works as intended in FF, IE9, Opera, and Chrome.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.preventDefault()` which stops the default submit action

```
$("#MyModal #form_reg").submit(function(event){
    var initial_id = 0;

    event.preventDefault();

   // your code here
```

Comment: Well, I do use event.preventDefault() in the correct situation.  But that is not the issue here.  The .submit event is not even being registered in IE7 (I've tried adding an alert statement as the first line after the .submit event, and it never displays).  As I mentioned above, my research so far has indicated that IE7 doesn't support the .submit event.  But the .click event supersedes the HTML5 Form Validation.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to keep the HTML5 form validation, but still be able to control the submit vs. non-submission as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

One of most cross-browser solutions for client-side form validation is to dynamically disable HTML5 validation (e.g. by adding `novalidate` attribute to `FORM` element with JS) and use same custom JavaScript validation codepath for all browsers.

So HTML5 validation will work *at least* in modern browsers when JS is disabled, while JavaScript validation will work in all browsers if JS is enabled.

Comment: The HTML5 (styled) form validation is actually working in IE7.  Use webshims/polyfiller for backwards browser compatibility.  I only mentioned the form validation as an explanation as to why I can't just use the .click event - since it supersedes the form validation.  If I allow the form to "flow" naturally, relying on its action tag (which is appropriate in 90% of my use cases) - the form validation works beautifully and presents in the same manner as all modern browsers.

Comment: The problem arises in the 10% of the cases where I need to change the action of the form submission - to either just close the modal form display while not taking any action or to perform a different action then the one that normally occurs.   Again, I could use the .click event, but that supersedes the form validation - as that only occurs on a .submit event.  And as far as I can tell, IE7 does not support the .submit event.   So, I'm just trying to figure out if any one has found a way to make IE7 work with the .submit event or come up with an equivalent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well the submit event should work in IE7. It should be normalized by jQuery. So it's very strange. I would say: Try to remove webshims (just for test) and look wether your submit handler is called, if it works, it might be a webshims bug (please report this. then). If it's still not working, it should be a jQuery bug.

To workaround your issue, you can do the following:

- remove validation $("#MyModal #form_reg").prop('noValidate', true);
- hook either into submit or button click
- and check validity inside of your handler using checkValidity + show validation messages